# Selenium IDE does not record clicking on 'OK' button of pop up

Tags: popup, click, selenium-ide

I am recording this application, and on clicking save this JavaScript alert box comes: "item added. Save?" along with an OK button. I have to click on the OK button in order to proceed with the page. IDE does not record the OK button click. Firebug does not recognise the object either.

How do I click on it?

KeyPress and Key Down are shown as deprecated commands, hence can't use those also.
If I could simulate pressing enter key that would work too.

I need the solution for Selenium IDE only, since all scripts are getting recorded in the same. Selenese or HTML solutions are welcome.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

use Command: `chooseOkOnNextConfirmation` helped me auto finished click OK button on the popup page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sendKeys(locator,key) command as keypress is deprecated in selenium ide 2.4

e.g. if you wanted to kepress "Enter" key then you can use sendkeys as

command     target    value

sendKeys    locator   ${KEY_ENTER}

but you will still need the locator.

Comment: can you suggest in any way, how to find the locator of the pop up?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations as to what can be replayed through Selenium IDE. The Selenese script recorded by Selenium IDE can be converted to a webdriver script.

Don't bother building tests using Selenium IDE, you will loose chance of building modular tests if you do so. If application changes in future, you will have to modify all your tests independently.

Your best bet is to use Selenium Webdriver with C# and also use some test framework like NUnit, so that non developers can run the tests using NUnit GUI using simple interface, that is the best approach I found so far.

Comment: Hi, using Webdriver is not an immediate option because we have recorded other applications in IDE and it should be consistent throughout. can you suggest in any way, how to find the locator of the pop up?

Comment: It is not possible with IDE because the popup is not a html object and will not have any locator. It is an ActiveX object.